# Button "popping" on a homepage

Tags: html

Below I have the code I used so that when you clicked the button, the picture would change the image of it as click, and then when you release the mouse, it will go back to original image making it look like the button pops in and out. The problem is that it only works when it wants to. It'll work until you release the mouse and the button has a broken image picture. Any help?

```
<p style="text-align: center; margin-top: -18.75px;">
<span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;"><a href="/index.php/about-
us/about-us"><img alt="Learn More About Company" 
onmousedown="this.src='/folder/image_pop.png';" 
onmouseup="this.src='/folder/image.png';" 
src="/folder/image.png" style="width: 144px; height: 
35px;" /></a></span></p>
```

Comment: Have you tried to open the image in the webbrowser? Broken imagens usually are due to lack of read permissions on the web server.

Comment: @Tony Yeah, but also keep in mind that the source image is the same image as the 'onmouseup' image and the source image appears just fine.

Comment: Why, oh why wouldn't you just use CSS?

Comment: @isherwood Unfortunately, I do not have access to the CSS file. The company I work for uses Joomla and only gives access through Joomla and not the core files.

Comment: Fair enough. You might be able to install ExtPlorer, for example, and get to the source files, or you may be able to install an extension just for CSS. It's much more elegant than click handlers. Actually,you can often put style tags right in the article.